# Batch file XCOPY cannot find existing directory

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, xcopy

I'm writing a small batch file to copy my C# project to another drive. I'm using `XCOPY` to copy an entire folder (We have some XP machines still, so `robocopy` isn't an option). However, when I run the batch file, it tells me that it cannot find the FILE specified (why it's looking for a file and not a folder I have no clue).

Here's my folder structure. I'd like to copy `folder` to the `program\dst` folder on the `O` drive.

```
src
-folder
-batchFile.bat

O
-program
--dst
```

My batchFile.bat contains the following line

```
XCOPY  ".\folder" "O:\program\dst" /E
```

When I run this, it says:

```
File Not Found - folder
```

even though it most definitely exists (as a folder, not a file).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest, using `.\folder` starts from the current directory, while you want the batch file's location:

```
XCOPY  "%~dp0folder" "O:\program\dst" /E
```

You could `cd` to the folder first, but this is more elegant IMO.

Comment: `%~dp0` already contains a trailing backslash, so it should be `"%~dp0folder"` (the parser corrects this error, but you should use the correct form nevertheless) Besides that, best answer, imho.

Comment: You're right, edited.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it works for me. I'm guessing you've created a shortcut to the batch file, and the start directory isn't correct. If so, adding a `cd` command to the start of the batch file to change directory into `src` should fix it, or alternatively use an absolute path to `folder` instead of a relative one:

```
cd "C:\Whatever\src"
XCOPY ".\folder" "O:\program\dst" /E
```

or

```
XCOPY "C:\Whatever\src\folder" "O:\program\dst" /E
```

Comment: No shortcut, I'm running it directly, so I'm not sure why the relative path isn't working (as it is preferred to use relative path for my needs)

Comment: @audiFanatic have you tried it with an absolute path?

Comment: Yea, and it works. But absolute isn't the best solution for my needs unfortunately.

Comment: @audiFanatic is creating a shortcut with the 'Start in' field set to the absolute path to 'src' a viable option for you?

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm trying to move these files between computers over a shared drive, so I'm not sure that I can use an absolute path at all because I cannot guarantee that it'll be valid.

Answer (score 0):

In your script put the below command to the very beginnig of your CMD file:

echo "%cd%"

Then observe what this command produces.

If your "folder" directory's full path is "C:\ABC\folder" then echo "%cd%" command should yield the output "C:\ABC". However, if you see something different from this then your XCOPY command fires file not found error. This is normal because XCOPY cannot determine whether "folder" is directory or file and assume it is default to a file.